Using .Net Aspire service discovery with generated client (openapi generator)
I am currently working on a project consisting of a asp.net backend and a blazor wasm frontend with .net aspire in between.
What I am trying to do is to let my backend generate a openapi documentation which then a openapi generator reads and generates a client for my frontend. So far this works find.
The issue I ran in now is that I cant get service discovery working with this generated client. As far as I can tell that is because the generated client isn't using the BaseAddress property of the HttpClient but instead has its own BasePath property, which it uses in the requests.
The only solution I could work out for now is to manually get the resolved address from my configuration using var apiServiceBaseAddress = configuration["services:apiservice:https:0"];
Is there a better way to do this?
Because this is the first time working with a generated client I am not sure that I am not doing something fundamentally wrong. It would be appreciated if you also could give me a pointer to where I can find more information on how to best work with this.

I would like to suggest you to use the HttpClient to handle and call the API from your Blazor app. This approach allows you to manage dynamically generated URLs centrally here is the code you can refer:
var apiServiceBaseAddress = configuration["services:apiservice:https:0"]; var httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(apiServiceBaseAddress) }; var apiClient = new ApiClient(httpClient); By this way, you can dynamically resolve and update the API base address without modifying code

fore more detail you could refer this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-9.0 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-web-api?view=aspnetcore-9.0

This is what I am already doing. I am using the  builder.Serviced.AddHttpClient method but that should result in the same outcome

option 1
one option is to set and pass the enviroment variables by your own using the WithArgs(...) and set it in your configuration manager or using .WithEnviroment():
using arguments:
.WithArgs(
     $"--Services:XXXX:https:0=https://routeToGeneratedClient:####",
     $"--Services:XXXX:http:0=http://routeToGeneratedClient:####"
);

using enviroment:
.WithEnvironment("Services:XXXX:https:0","https://routeToGeneratedClient:####")
.WithEnvironment("Services:XXXX:http:0","http://routeToGeneratedClient:####")

with args you have to set the in your configuration as a source (I also added enviroment so it will behave as microsoft suggest commandLines->enviroments->appsettings [high priority to lower])
this is how I do it in my projects that depends on configuration pass it or not from aspire (I can execute the projects standalone and fallback to other configurations different from when is running from net aspire)
builder.Configuration
.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{builder.Environment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange:true)
.AddEnvironmentVariables()
.AddCommandLine(args ?? []);

option 2
if you implement a reverse proxy as yarp or ocelot it can redirect to calls from frontend to the generated client (you need to hardcode or set the option 1 in for yarp or ocelot).
option 2.1
Maybe no the best option but you could create a sort of (proxy or dummy) project, add it in NetAspire.Host program with a name and port, the service discovery will create the corresponding
Services:XXXX: 
Services:XXXX:https: 
Services:XXXX:https:0: https://localhost:####
Services:XXXX:http: 
Services:XXXX:http:0: http://localhost:####

then you just reference it in your frontend project or others that depends on.
